# Duplicate a google map to a separate <div> element on page

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I have one istance of a google map on a page. I'm using the following line of code to get the map and assign it to a new variable.

```
 newmap = map.getMap();
```

When I print newmap to console it shows that the map is being assigned to the variable. I now want to duplicate that map with the exact same options into the following div....

```
 <div id="map-larger-canvas"></div>
```

Any idea's how I would do this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [clone google map instance](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5042170/clone-google-map-instance)

Answer (score 0):

Define option for every map and after init twice:

```
var map_options = {
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(41.811729,12.738513),
        zoom: 8,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    }

function initialize() {
    var map1 = document.getElementById('map-1st');
    var map_canvas = document.getElementById('map-larger-canvas');

    var map1 = new google.maps.Map(map1, map_options)
    var map2 = new google.maps.Map(map_canvas, map_options);
}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

I use Json in this way, take a look:

```
$('#map_canvas_europe').gmap().bind('init', function() { 
    // This URL won't work on your localhost, so you need to change it
    // see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy
    $.getJSON( 'json/locations_europe.json', function(data) { 
        $.each( data.markers, function(i, marker) {
            $('#map_canvas_europe').gmap('addMarker', { 
                'position': new google.maps.LatLng(marker.latitude, marker.longitude), 
                'bounds': true 
            }).click(function() {
                $('#map_canvas_europe').gmap('openInfoWindow', { 'content': marker.content }, this);
            });
        });
    });
});

$('#map_canvas_asia').gmap().bind('init', function() { 
    // This URL won't work on your localhost, so you need to change it
    // see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy
    $.getJSON( 'json/locations_asia.json', function(data) { 
        $.each( data.markers, function(i, marker) {
            $('#map_canvas_asia').gmap('addMarker', { 
                'position': new google.maps.LatLng(marker.latitude, marker.longitude), 
                'bounds': true 
            }).click(function() {
                $('#map_canvas_asia').gmap('openInfoWindow', { 'content': marker.content }, this);
            });
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: Hi djSkAV, thanks for your reply. As my map is generated by a mappress plugin where I have no control over map options, Dr.Molles suggestion above to append the map to the larger div seems to be less work for me.