# google maps v3 duplicate a map instance

Tags: javascript, html, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

Is it possible to duplicate a once loaded map instance?

So as to display multiple identical maps (which would all do the exact same thing) in multiple divs (without creating new map instances with the API).

I hope you get what I'm trying to say.

Thanks!

Comment: possible duplicate of [clone google map instance](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5042170/clone-google-map-instance)

Comment: Depends very much on what you mean by "do the exact same thing". If you want two maps simultaneously displayed and ganged to each other, then you would need two map instances and potentially a heap of code to perform the ganging. If you want two non-simultaneous renderings of the same maps then take a look at the link provided by @Dr.Molle.

Comment: @Dr.Molle, that solution only moves the map I wish to copy it.

Comment: @Beetroot-Beetroot I would say I want them ganged but only one map would offer interaction. Basically any data the API will download and render for a one map instance I would like to render in multiple divs.

Comment: @Matekk: It's not a solution, it's the same question with the answer: **If you need to copy it, I guess the only way might be to create completely new map and create all the objects from scratch.**